# Per platform configuration (config.xml) on PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap 3.1 application that I build remotely on PhoneGap Build.
In my app there is a single `config.xml` file at the root of the project. This file contains:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
```

However I would like to restrict the orientation to portrait mode in iOS.
I've randomly tried :

```
<preference gap:platform="ios" name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

and

```
<gap:platform name="ios">
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
</gap:platform>
```

but none of these seem to work.

How can I set preferences for specific platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PGB we now have the ability to add to the info.plist file. So in your config.xml put this:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" overwrite="true">
   <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
   </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

Read more and see this exact example here:
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/