# Per platform configuration (config.xml) on cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

something like-

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" overwrite="true">
   <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
   </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

like the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998325/per-platform-configuration-config-xml-on-phonegap-build) regarding Phonegap.

is there an option for it in config.xml on Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For screen orientation, adding `<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />` will result in the CLI adding the specific tags in the platform specific config files each time you build (androidmanifest.xml for android and sorry I don't know much about IOS...)

If you want to force the orientation for ios but not android, you can try this :

```
<platform name="ios">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
</platform>
```

For other options, there are tags that are recognised only by some platforms so you add them to config.xml and the cli uses it or not depending on the platform. See [here fore android-only options](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration) and [here for ios-only options](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html#iOS%20Configuration).

For things like plugins, you use the cli to customize each platform, but don't touch config.xml.

For other things unfortunatly you may have to manually edit the specific platform config file (ie androidmanifest.xml) once the platform has been added to the project. When you build the project, those options should be kept in the config file.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I'm asking the question is because the option I'm looking for does not exist in the "iOS-only options" link you gave to cordova's documentation. I need to change the iOS CFBundleDisplayName, and I want to use the per-platform config because I can't type hebrew in the '<name>' tag, it makes the 'cordova build/run' process fail.

Comment: Is your config.xml file saved in UTF/8? And can't you use english name in config.xml and manually modify the xxx-Info.plist file somewhere in your platforms/ios folder?

Comment: its saved in utf 8. I can edit it manually, but then I'd have to do it each time i generate the cordova ios build.

Comment: Ok then, even though there is no perfect solution for what I'm looking for right now, this answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has long since been answered, but I found this handy documentation page just this afternoon when building my first Cordova based app:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#orientation

Hope this helps anyone else that stumbles upon this page.